# Query builder dbflow conditional query

Tags: orm, query-builder, dbflow

how can i build a query based on certain conditions .

i tried doing this

```
QueryBuilder builder = SQlite.Select().from(Table)
    if(condition) {
         builder.where(something)
    }
Cursor c = builder.query;
```

but it is not permitted.

I have to query my database on conditions that i have saved in preferences . I googled  and searched everywhere  in thr docs but couldn't find a single example .   do this feature exists in dbflow if yes then how if no is thr any other orm (like greenDAO) with this feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* create conditional queries in DBFlow. To query a table's columns you must append `_Table` to your class name, then access its property. These `_Table` classes are generated during build time.

The most simple query would be this one:

```
SQLite.select()
      .from(YourTable.class)
      .where(YourTable_Table.id.eq(someId)
      .queryList();
```

You can also add new conditions by using `.and` and `.or` in your query:

```
SQLite.select()
      .from(YourTable.class)
      .where(YourTable_Table.id.eq(someId)
      .and(YourTable_Table.name.eq(someName)
      .queryList();
```

For a cleaner code, you can also group conditions into condition groups like this:

```
ConditionGroup conditionGroup = ConditionGroup.clause();
conditionGroup.and(YourTable_Table.id.eq(someId);

if (someCondition) {
    conditionGroup.and(YourTable_Table.name.eq(someName);
}

return SQLite.select()
      .from(YourTable.class)
      .where(conditionGroup)
      .queryList();
```

Answer (score 2):

found two ways of achieving  my problem

1.from @trevjonez(trevor jones)

```
Where<SomeModel> query = SQLite.select()
                               .from(SomeModel.class)
                               .where(SomeModel_Table.date_field.greaterThan(someValue));

if(someCondition) {
   query = query.and(SomeModel_Table.other_field.eq(someOtherValue));
} else {
   query = query.and(SomeModel_Table.another_field.isNotNull());
}

Cursor cursor = query.query();
//do stuff with cursor and close it
—
```

2.from @zshock using ConditionalGroup

```
ConditionGroup conditionGroup = ConditionGroup.clause();
conditionGroup.and(YourTable_Table.id.eq(someId);

if (someCondition) {
    conditionGroup.and(YourTable_Table.name.eq(someName);
}

return SQLite.select()
      .from(YourTable.class)
      .where(conditionGroup)
      .queryList();
```